# LoadRunner: Parameterization of JSON file

Tags: loadrunner

I am preparing REST API script in LoadRunner with a long request and I created a json file and called it inside BodyFilePath, but while doing parameterisation, it's not changing value in the JSON file uploaded in Extra Files location in LR. How to resolve it?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you are using.

Comment: In `Body` parameter, just mention the variable name {jsonVariable}. This will pass the JSON in the Body.